# Automatically move installed packages to site-lisp to benefit all user accounts

Tags: package, package-repositories, site-lisp

I have scripts to setup virtual machine images, where emacs packages are installed for the **root** account. Currently, I manually copy them to the appropriate site-lisp directory, i.e. one of those defined by package-directory-list --  either /usr/share/emacs/24.3/site-lisp/elpa or /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa.

While the above approach works for making installed packages accessible to normal user account, I would prefer to avoid hand editing the packages directory.

**Is there a way to automate this process in `package.el` itself ?**

Comment: I feel like there is a useful question in here somewhere, but as stated it's unclear.

Comment: I edited the question quite liberally to emphasize what I think is your question. Feel free to revert/edit if you disagree. The original question was unclear

Answer (score 2):

Would it help to simply set [`package-user-dir`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/package-user-dir) before installing the packages?

```
(setq package-user-dir "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/site-lisp/elpa")
```

Assuming you have write access, package.el will install the packages there.